# Sprite Body can not jump perfectly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

In my demo game my sprite body can not jump smoothly. When i press jump button body jump but can not perfect.

I show you code.

```
-(void)jump:(b2Body*)ballBody
{
    if (jumpSprte.active==YES) 
    {
        b2Vec2 force=b2Vec2(0,200);
       // ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
        ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(force); 
    }

}
```

Code is true but can not jump perfect so is any one know than tell me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "perfect" in this context. Perfect means "having no flaws", so saying it's not perfect is just like saying "something's wrong". If you want an answer, let us know *what exactly* is wrong.

Comment: Okay I want to jump my sprite like http://www.ikbentomas.nl/other/box2d/

Comment: By adjusting friction, density, restitution, linearDamping, angularDamping of the body u can get right effect:)

Comment: I did all the things but it can not jump smoothly and not getting right effect..